# Use of overloaded operator[] is ambiguous

Tags: c++

Simplified code as below:

```
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

struct object{
  operator std::string(){return "";}
}

struct foo{
  foo operator[](std::string_view s){
    return foo{};
  }
  
  template <typename T>
  operator T(){
    return object{};
  }
};

int main(){
  foo f;
  std::string s = f["a"];
}
```

clang gives an error:

> ```
> error: use of overloaded oeprator '[]' is ambiguous (with oeprand types 'foo' and 'const char*')
> note: candidate function foo operator[](std::string_view s)
> note: built-in candidate operator[](long, const char*)
> note: built-in candidate operator[](long, const volatile char*)
> ```

but gcc compiles above code successfully.

clang version is 12.0.1, gcc is 7.5.0

I'm confused, which compiler is right?

Comment: Please make sure you *copy and paste* the code and the errors you want to show us. That could (and in your case does) add unrelated errors and typos. Don't rewrite them into the question. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: your code wont even compile with all these typos in the source code.

Comment: sorry, I think I have fixed the typo. I can't just copy paste them right now, because my dev environment is a virtual machine without internet connection. the comment is not important, I have removed it.

Comment: You can independently test the code you give us though, to make sure it reproduces the errors.

Comment: Fun fact: `"foo"[3] == 3["foo"]`

Comment: `template <typename T> operator T()` nice way to shoot your legs multiple times

Comment: Clang seems to instantiate the templated conversion operator with `T` being `std::ptrdiff_t`. Non-templated version, where the error is generated also with GCC: https://godbolt.org/z/dzfnson4x. There is the built-in `operator[](std::ptrdiff_t, const char *)`, which then causes ambiguity. The question is why GCC does not behave the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```cpp
> template <typename T>
> operator T(){
>     return object{};
> }
> ```

I think clang is correct here, since this snippet makes the `foo` class convertible to any type, and [viable template functions are supposed to be instantiated](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Details) before overload resolution comes into play:

> Before overload resolution begins, the functions selected by name
> lookup and template argument deduction are combined to form the set of
> candidate functions

As you can see, the overload struggles with the following arguments: `(long, const char*)`, so it has to be expression similar to this `3["a"]` which is perfectly legal as per [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Explanation):

> ```
> expr1 [ expr2 ]
> ```
>
> For the built-in operator, one of the expressions (either `expr1` or
> `expr2`) must be a glvalue of type “array of `T`” or a prvalue of type
> “pointer to T”, while the other expression (`expr2` or `expr1`,
> respectively) must be a prvalue of unscoped enumeration or integral
> type. The result of this expression has the type `T`

---

However it also gives a clue how to differentiate between built-in subscript and custom overloads:

> ```
> expr1 [ { expr, ... } ]
> ```
>
> The form with brace-enclosed list inside the square brackets is only used to call an overloaded `operator[]`.

So you should be good if the said example is written like this:

```
int main(){
    foo f;
    std::string s = f[{"a"}];
    return 0;
}
```

Or convert the subscript to string explicitly, so the compiler doesn't confuse it with built-in operator for arrays:

```cpp
int main(){
    using namespace std::string_literals;
    
    foo f;
    std::string s = f["a"s];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your edit is incorrect, return value type has no impact on overload resolution, so the fact that `char` is not convertible to `std::string` does not change the resolution for `operator[]`.

Comment: I agree with @Holt. Same problem, no `std::string` involved: https://godbolt.org/z/xsoxofPzT.

Comment: @Holt, thanks for the input. Rolled back the edit